# Receiver class is anonymous so how can i declare receiver in manifest file in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

i am android developer i want to declare my broadcast receiver in manifest file
but problem is " i am call Receiver by anonymous class "
so this class donot have name then how can i declare without name class in manifest file..

Comment: Why do you want to declare it in the manifest file?  Or why do you want to keep the receiver anonymous?

Comment: Didn't get it. You want to broadcast intent for receiver (i.e., call Receiver) from anonymous class or your BroadcastReceiver is anonymous class ?

Comment: My BroadcastReceiver is anonymous class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For broadcast receivers that you can't declare via codes then you need to declare it in manifest and you have to provide a concrete class for your receiver.

But for those receivers that can be registered via codes, you can use anonymous class instance of BroadcastReceiver.

**--EDIT---**

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
 <application>

     <!-- some other codes here -->

     <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Sample filter to listen when device boot is completed -->
            <!-- This type of receiver cant be declared in codes -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

 </application>
```

Comment: Can say how to write in Manifest